# SQL joining queries from two databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have queries from two different tables that group their respective data (count) by yyyy-mm.  I would like to take the count results from both queries and display them together.  Following are my two queries:

QUERY 1:

```
    DECLARE @ThisMonth DATETIME
    SET @ThisMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')

    select cast(cast(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.date as date) as varchar(7)) AS     [MONTH], COUNT(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRID) AS [NCRs]
    FROM TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails 
    ON T_FatigueNCRs.NCRID = TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver 
    ON TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.DriverID = TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.ID
    WHERE (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.CancelYN = 0) 
    AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.FleetID = 2) 
    AND  (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.Active = 1) 
    AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRTypeID = 1) 
    AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.Details <> 'Driving Hours Breach As Per Breach Report') 
    AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @ThisMonth)   
    AND TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.Date <  @ThisMonth)
    GROUP BY cast(cast(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.date as date) as varchar(7))
```

RETURNS:

```
MONTH     NCRs
2013-08   43
2013-09   34
2013-10   53
```

QUERY 2:

```
    DECLARE @ThisMonth DATETIME
    SET @ThisMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')

    select cast(cast(landing.dbo.landing_runs.date as date) as varchar(7)) as [MONTH], COUNT(*) as [RUNS]
    from landing.dbo.Landing_Runs
    where (landing.dbo.Landing_Runs.date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @ThisMonth)   
    AND landing.dbo.Landing_Runs.date <  @ThisMonth)
    GROUP BY cast(cast(landing.dbo.landing_runs.date as date) as varchar(7))
```

RETURNS:

```
MONTH     RUNS
2013-08   4626
2013-09   4042
2013-10   4481
```

What I would like to do is somehow join these two separate queries so that the results appear as:

```
MONTH     RUNS     NCRs
2013-08   4626     43
2013-09   4042     34
2013-10   4481     53
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just join them together as subqueries. I chose `INNER JOIN` below but feel free to change it to a different type of join.

```
DECLARE @ThisMonth DATETIME
SET @ThisMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')

select t1.[MONTH], t1.[NCRs], t2.[RUNS]
from
(
    select cast(cast(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.date as date) as varchar(7)) AS     [MONTH], COUNT(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRID) AS [NCRs]
    FROM TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails 
    ON T_FatigueNCRs.NCRID = TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver 
    ON TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.DriverID = TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.ID
    WHERE (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.CancelYN = 0) 
    AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.FleetID = 2) 
    AND  (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.Active = 1) 
    AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRTypeID = 1) 
    AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.Details <> 'Driving Hours Breach As Per Breach Report') 
    AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @ThisMonth)   
    AND TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.Date <  @ThisMonth)
    GROUP BY cast(cast(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.date as date) as varchar(7))
) t1
inner join
(
    select cast(cast(landing.dbo.landing_runs.date as date) as varchar(7)) as [MONTH], COUNT(*) as [RUNS]
    from landing.dbo.Landing_Runs
    where (landing.dbo.Landing_Runs.date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @ThisMonth)   
    AND landing.dbo.Landing_Runs.date <  @ThisMonth)
    GROUP BY cast(cast(landing.dbo.landing_runs.date as date) as varchar(7))
) t2 on t1.[MONTH] = t2.[MONTH]
```

Answer (score 0):

If both queries will return the same Month ranges, you can join them together with an Inner Join. Otherwise, I would create a table variable containing all the months you want to display. Let me know if I can help you with that.

```
 DECLARE @ThisMonth DATETIME
    SET @ThisMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')

select ncrs.[Month],ncrs.NCRs,runs.Runs
from    (
        select
            cast(cast(ncr.date as date) as varchar(7)) AS [MONTH],
            COUNT(ncrd.NCRID) AS [NCRs]
        FROM TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs ncr 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails 
                ON T_FatigueNCRs.NCRID = ncrd.NCRID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver 
                ON ncr.DriverID = TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.ID
        WHERE (ncrd.CancelYN = 0) 
            AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.FleetID = 2) 
            AND  (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.Active = 1) 
            AND (ncrd.NCRTypeID = 1) 
            AND (ncrd.Details <> 'Driving Hours Breach As Per Breach Report') 
            AND (ncr.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @ThisMonth)   
            AND ncr.Date <  @ThisMonth)
        GROUP BY cast(cast(ncr.date as date) as varchar(7))
        ) ncrs
    inner join  (
                select
                    cast(cast(landing.dbo.landing_runs.date as date) as varchar(7)) as [MONTH],
                    COUNT(*) as [RUNS]
                from landing.dbo.Landing_Runs
                where (landing.dbo.Landing_Runs.date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @ThisMonth)   
                    AND landing.dbo.Landing_Runs.date <  @ThisMonth)
                GROUP BY cast(cast(landing.dbo.landing_runs.date as date) as varchar(7))
                ) runs
        on runs.[Month] = ncrs.NCRs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the 2 queries by a union, distinguishing between the two using a column where you specify whether it's NCRs or RUNS, and then aggregate using a case statement on the top layer, grouping by month. See below:

```
DECLARE @ThisMonth DATETIME
SET @ThisMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')

select [   MONTH ],
       sum(case
         when aggtype = 'NCR' then
          [ NCRs ]
         else
          0
       end as ncrs, sum(case
         when aggtype = 'RUNS' then
          [ RUNS ]
         else
          0
       end as runs from (select 'NCR' as aggtype,
                          cast(cast(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.date as date) as
                               varchar(7)) AS [ MONTH ],
                          COUNT(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRID) AS [ NCRs ]
                     FROM TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails
                       ON T_FatigueNCRs.NCRID =
                          TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver
                       ON TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.DriverID =
                          TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.ID
                    WHERE (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.CancelYN = 0)
                      AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.FleetID = 2)
                      AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_Driver.Active = 1)
                      AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.NCRTypeID = 1)
                      AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRDetails.Details <>
                          'Driving Hours Breach As Per Breach Report')
                      AND (TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.Date >=
                          DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @ThisMonth) AND
                          TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.Date <
                          @ThisMonth)
                    GROUP BY cast(cast(TransportAppv6.dbo.T_FatigueNCRs.date as date) as
                                  varchar(7))
                   union all
                   select 'RUNS' as aggtype,
                          cast(cast(landing.dbo.landing_runs.date as date) as
                               varchar(7)) as [ MONTH ],
                          COUNT(*) as [ RUNS ]
                     from landing.dbo.Landing_Runs
                    where (landing.dbo.Landing_Runs.date >=
                          DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @ThisMonth) AND
                          landing.dbo.Landing_Runs.date < @ThisMonth)
                    GROUP BY cast(cast(landing.dbo.landing_runs.date as date) as
                                  varchar(7))) group by [ MONTH ]
```